# How to hide all except for one div in a cocoa web view?

Tags: javascript, facebook, html, webview

I have Facebook.com open in a cocoa web view, and I want to to hide all the divs in the page except for the Facebook chat div (the class is "fbDockWrapper").
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try calling this function

```
function hideAll(){

    var ele = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for(i=0;i<ele.length;i++){
        var divelement = ele[i];

        if(divelement.getAttribute("class") != "fbDockWrapper"){
            divelement.style.display = 'none';
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: var ele = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for(i=0;i<ele.length;i++){
        var divelement = ele[i];

        if(divelement.getAttribute("class") == "fbDockWrapper fbDockWrapperRight"){
            divelement.style.display = 'none';
      }
}

The above succeeds in getting rid of just the chat box, but when i make it "!=", everything disappears...

Comment: Well.. It may be b/c you have nested DIV tags. pl provide your generated HTML source so that we can check. Also , check this in firefox as IE is not very good in handling getElementsByTagName function.

Comment: OK..is it possible for you to provide generated HTML source ? if not , just try playing with different attributes to uniquely filter out your chat window so that rest of them can be made hidden.

Comment: okay, so how would i remove the div with id FB_HiddenContainer?

Comment: use like this if(divelement.getAttribute("id") == "FB_HiddenContainer"){divelement.style.display = 'none';
}